# Add 'install selected .deb files' as command in Nautilus actions

Tags: debian, software-installation, nautilus

Running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` in a terminal opened in '/folder', installs all debs in the location '/folder'.

What command to add in [`nautilus-actions`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions/) (Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool) so that **only selected** deb files are installed?

---

For example, I looked for a script to run a command in a terminal and according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/5378) model I have created this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Get a Bash shell
spawn -noecho bash

# Wait for a prompt
expect "$ "

# Type something
send "sudo dpkg -i"

# Hand over control to the user
interact

exit
```

To run that script I have created an action with Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool and tried to make settings to make it open within a selected location and for the selected deb files. The first part works, based on a command like: `gnome-terminal -e  "/path/to/the/script" --working-directory=%f`

But the terminal just contains that command to install all debs from that folder, without considering the selection o files (in the context menu of which I can make the command appear: but it will affect all files, not just those selected).

Comment: For example in caja, the alternative to Nautilus of mate-desktop you have a ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts where you can put you scripts files, that can be used in context menus. Nautilus has feature alike.

Comment: @sebelk - with [nautilus-actions](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions/) the scripts are created and added through a GUI. but the script needs to contain a command, and that is what i am asking for. (e.g. - to select flv files and extract audio **from these selected files** i have added the command `-e "parallel avconv -i '{}' -map 0:1 -c:a copy '{}.m4a' -- %F". how to do that for installing **selected** deb files?)

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
#!/bin/sh
dpkg -i "$@"
```

HTH

Comment: is this the exact script, or a generic form with variables?

Comment: Yup, I've not tested on a debian distro but on caja (Fedora) I have that the following script:
    #!/bin/sh  
    md5sum "$@" | xargs -0  matedialog --info --title "md5sum" --text  

matedialog it's like zenity, gdialog, etc, you have the same feature in Nautilus  take a look at http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-960962-start-0.html

Comment: would you give me more details? if i were to add `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to the scripts you presented, where should i put it? all this is rather obscure to me, although it seems too simple to you :) . also: on the link you provided: it is about gnome 2 vs gnome 3. i am in elementaryOS myself. what i want is to apply a given script (to install deb) just to the selected files, if possible

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works in PCManFM and therefore should work in Nautilus is something like this: create a folder `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions`, then create a file there. In terminal:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/install_deb.desktop
```

With this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Name[en]=Install deb files
Profiles=profile-zero;
Icon=gdebi
TargetLocation=true
MimeTypes=application/vnd.debian.binary-package;
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'sudo dpkg -i "%f"'
```